# What is the best way to connect two many-to-many (belongsToMany) together in laravel?

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

I have two working many-to-many (**belongsToMany**) relations. I am looking for a third connection that connects these two relations together. For now I am doing it myself in a manual way but I really wonder if there is a built in Laravel way. Plus what would be the most efficient and proper way to accomplish this?

*Here is a short presentation of the tables:*

```
users 
 name
 email
 password

role_user 
 role_id
 user_id

roles 
 name

permission_role
 permission_id
 role_id

permissions 
 name
 route
```

The **users** table is related to **roles** with **belongsToMany** using the **role_user** pivot table,
the **permissions** table is related to the **roles** table using the **permission_role** table. everything okay but how to relate users and permissions together. how can i get something like this `$permissions = App\User::find(1)->permissions()->get();` done in a Laravel way.

> I can't use something like **hasManyThrough** relation because none of the tables **users**, **roles** and **permissions** have any relating columns like **users.role_id** or **roles.user_id** for i could use

Comment: I came across a similar problem. [Here](stackoverflow.com/questions/37393687/laravel-5-2-query-many-to-many-to-one) is a question I asked with an answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks @ThomasVanderVeen i do it in a similar way. actually i wonder if there is a laravel way for this relation.